# Can I use Typescript 2.4.2 with Ionic 3.8.0?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Can I use Typescript 2.4.2 with Ionic 3.8.0 ?

$ ionic info

cli packages: (C:***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3
Node              : v6.11.5
npm               : 3.10.9
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\fahem.belili\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: You can really do anything if you put your mind to it. But, to answer the question TYPESCRIPT just evals out to javascript so yes you can. THere will be hoops you need to jump through but again TYPESCRIPT just evaluates out to javascript in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not recommended** since the Ionic team has not tested it with `3.8.0`.Hope you can easily upgrade your app to the `3.9.2` and use TS `2.4.2` with `Angular 5`.

Here are the [**release notes of 3.9.2**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases)

Comment: thanks for your advice. 
For my application i have some problems when upgrading to 3.9.2 so I prefer wait

Comment: Hope you can share your issues with us no? I highly recommend to upgrade it to Angular 5. It gives great performance and very small package size.